# How to access provider value in Init state

Tags: flutter

How do I access the value in a provider model from the init function or a workaround?

Basically, when my App loads, I save some value in a provider model.

One value is a search variable. Then I am redirected to a loading page where I need this value to get the data and render a list.

I am retrieving the data in the init method.

-- My Main function

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
   Provider<UserModel>(
      builder: (_) => UserModel(),
      child: Jobs(),
    ),
  ); //added
}
```

This is a snippet of my Jobs page

```dart
case '/main':
   return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => JobsHomePage(title: "jobs"));
   break;
```

This is list page that displays this list
 --- JobsHomePage()

```dart
void initState() {
    searchVal = Provider.of<UserModel>(context).searchVal;
    jb =load(searchVal);
}
```

Then I have a builder method that iterates thru 'jb' and prints the value

The error I am getting is inherited error

flutter: When an inherited widget changes, for example, if the value of Theme.of() changes, it's dependent

Thanks for your help... I did not post the entire code because it is very long and I get some "all code" error in the stack.

Comment: Same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363665/dependoninheritedelement-was-called-before-initstate-in-flutter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access `context` in `initState`, but you can access it in `didChangeDependencies`.
According to [offical docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) it's called right after `initState` and it can use `context`, so it can call `Provider.of<T>(context)`

Answer (score 39):

The accepted answer by Mikhail is fine if you don't need to update the widget again after performing some task in the `didChangeDependencies` method. (Which is not the case most of the time.)

But it will not work if you need to notify the listeners after performing the task.

The context *is* accessible in `initState`.
You need to add the argument `listen: false` to the Provider.

The [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider/of.html) say

> listen: false is necessary to be able to call `Provider.of` inside `[State.initState]` or the `create` method of providers like so: ...

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final _store = Provider.of<RecorderStore>(context, listen: false);
  }
```

Now as to why overriding `didChangeDependencies` is not a good idea:

In the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) it says

> For example, if the previous call to build referenced an InheritedWidget that later changed, the framework would call this method to notify this object about the change.

Therefore when you use `ChangeNotifierProvider` for example, when you call `notifyListeners()` that will call the `didChangeDependencies` method.

So when you call `notifyListeners` through `didChangeDependencies` it will lead to an infinite loop.

Or even if you don't call `notifyListeners` explicitly, whenever the `didChangeDepencies` method is called, the code is executed multiple times.

So better to use `listen: false` in the initState to ensure that the code is executed only once.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem. I have store which should take singleton dependencies in constructor and using didChangeDependencies trigger continuous rebuilds. Using `listen: false` solved the problem

Comment: This is a great answer. This should be marked as accepted answer. I have been passing parameters the conventional way when I needed the value from provider. That was redundant. This solves my problem a great deal

Comment: I get a null error because Provider takes a tick to populate, and doing a null check doesn't work in initstate...how to use the value?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij What should we do if we have to notify the listeners and have to call provider in initState?

Comment: @Patzu I think you can do a `notifyListeners()` as you normally would?