# dependOnInheritedElement() was called before initstate() in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am currently having an issue while fetching a `Provider' value in`initstate`.

I want to set a default value in dropdown in an Appbar and other parts in body. But I got an error saying `dependOnInheritedElement() was called before initstate() in flutter`.

My full code is below

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:test_eoil/model/button_data.dart';
import 'package:test_eoil/model/output_data.dart';
import 'screen/screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(providers: [
//      ChangeNotifierProvider<ChordData>(create: (context) => ChordData()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<OutputData>(create: (context) => OutputData()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ButtonData>(create: (context) => ButtonData())
    ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Screen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`screen.dart` in screen folder

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:test_eoil/model/button_data.dart';
import 'package:test_eoil/model/output_data.dart';


class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {

  Widget dropdownWidget() {
    return DropdownButton<Button>(
      items: Provider.of<ButtonData>(context).buttons.map((Button value) {
        return new DropdownMenuItem<Button>(
          value: value,
          child: new Text(value.type.toString()),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (Button newValue) {
        Provider.of<ButtonData>(context).setSelectedItem(newValue);
      },
      value: Provider.of<ButtonData>(context).selectedButton,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<ButtonData>(context).selectedButton = Provider.of<ButtonData>(context).buttons.first;
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<OutputData>(
        builder: (context, outputData, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("${Provider.of<ButtonData>(context).selectedButton}"), // new Text(widget.title), // "${Provider.of<ButtonData>(context).selectedButton.key}"
              actions: <Widget>[
                dropdownWidget(),
              ],
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 24.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                      child: outputData.outputs[0].output3.length > 2
                          ? Text(
                          '${outputData.outputs[0].output3.substring(1, outputData.outputs[0].output3.length-1)}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ))
                          : Text('${outputData.outputs[0].output3}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 24.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                      child: outputData.outputs[0].output2.length > 2
                          ? Text(
                          '${outputData.outputs[0].output2.substring(1, outputData.outputs[0].output2.length-1)}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ))
                          : Text('${outputData.outputs[0].output2}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 24.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                      child: Text('${outputData.outputs[0].output1}',  //  outputData.outputs[0].output1
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: new Divider(),
                ),
                Column(children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    buildButton("CLEAR"),
                    buildButton(""),
                    buildButton("PLAY"),
                    //                    buildButton("/")
                  ]),
                ])
              ],
            )));
  }



  Widget buildButton(String buttonText) {
    return new Expanded(
      child: new OutlineButton(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: new Text(
          buttonText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        onPressed: () => print("test"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`button_data.dart` in model folder

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
//import 'dart:collection';

class Button {
  final int id;
  final String type;
  final String numberone;
  final String numbertwo;
  final String numberthree;

  Button({this.id, this.type, this.numberone, this.numbertwo, this.numberthree});


}

class ButtonData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Button> _buttons = [
    Button(
      type: "A",
      numberone: "1",
      numbertwo: "2",
      numberthree: "3",
    ),
    Button(
      type: "B",
      numberone: "A",
      numbertwo: "B",
      numberthree: "C",
    ),
  ];

  List<Button> get buttons => _buttons;
  Button _selectedButton;
  Button get selectedButton => _selectedButton;

  set selectedButton(Button button) {
    _selectedButton = button;
    notifyListeners();
  }


  void setSelectedItem(Button s) {
    _selectedButton = s;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Button getKey(String value) {
    return _buttons
        .where((button) => button.type == value).first;
  }

  String getNumberOne(String value) {
    return _buttons
        .where((button) => button.type == value)
        .map((button) => (button.numberone))
        .toString();
  }

  String getNumberTwo(String value) {
    return _buttons
        .where((button) => button.type == value)
        .map((button) => (button.numbertwo))
        .toString();
  }

  String getNumberThree(String value) {
    return _buttons
        .where((button) => button.type == value)
        .map((button) => (button.numberthree))
        .toString();
  }

}
```

`output_data.dart` in model folder

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


class Output {

  final int id;
  String output1;
  String output2;
  String output3;

  Output({this.id, this.output1, this.output2, this.output3});

}


class OutputData extends ChangeNotifier {

  List<Output> _outputs = [
    Output(output1: 'Hello', output2: 'Hi', output3: 'Nice'),
    Output(output1: 'Haha', output2: 'Bye', output3: 'Sad'),
  ];

  List<Output> get outputs {
    return _outputs;
  }


}
```

To be honest, I want to make it work without `initstate()` if possible(I heard that provider pattern doesn't need stful)

The reason I come up with an `initstate()` is this is the only solution (as much as I know) to set the default value in provider.

Hope you guys help me!

---

Issue is solved by adding Button_data constructor in `button_data.dart`.

```
ButtonData () {
    _selectedButton = _buttons.first;
  }
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I also mentioned in my previous answer that `Provider.of(context)` is supposed to be used inside the widget tree, and anything that is outside of the `build()` method, is not in the widget tree. But if you still want to use it, then you need to set the `listen` parameter to `false`.

Like so:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<ButtonData>(context, listen: false).selectedButton = Provider.of<ButtonData>(context, listen: false).buttons.first;
    super.initState();
  }
```

But as you mentioned in your question, you don't want to use `initState` to set the default value. In every programming language, when you declare a variable with a value, that value becomes it's initial / default value, and you can change it later.

Instead of using `initState`, you can edit the following in your `ButtonData` class.

```
//Remove this.
List<Button> get buttons => _buttons;
  Button _selectedButton;
  Button get selectedButton => _selectedButton;

//Instead, Use this.
List<Button> get buttons => _buttons;
Button _selectedButton = _buttons.first;
Button get selectedButton => _selectedButton;

//This will declare the `selectedButton` variable with a default value.
//Happy coding! :)
```

Comment: I set  the listen parameter to `false` in `initial value`. The same error returns. you can check it since I uploaded a full code.

Comment: The second way - declaring a variablie with a value in `button_data.dart`.- That's what I intended at first. But when I declared a variable with a value like you said, error returns `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`.  you can also check it since I uploaded a full code.

Comment: If possible, I would like to fix the second issue `only static member...`. But to the best of my knowledge, it was difficult to solve. That's why I tried to bypass it in a different way.

Comment: Issue solved. I just edited my block. Really Thanks for looking at my question. @BasedMusa

Answer (score 19):

Another solution when "dependOnInheritedElement() was called before initState()" could also be to access BuildContext safely in the initState method. It could be done by the following:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
// your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me ->

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final authViewModel = Provider.of<AuthViewModel>(context, listen: false);

      authViewModel.getToken();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
`enter code here`
});

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32552576)