# Unexpected behaviour Flutter whilst using Future.delayed in combination with Widgets

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using a PageController-like structure to open and close my widgets. The expected behaviour is to go to the `AfterGame` widget after 49 seconds has elapsed. This does indeed happen. However, when this transition happens, the `navigateToNextScreenAfterNSeconds` is called again somehow, because 49 seconds after the transition (regardless of which widget is open), we transition once again to the `AfterGame` widget.

It seems that the `navigateToNextScreenAfterNSeconds` is somehow called upon opening **and** upon closing the widget, whilst I only want to call it once, when opening the widget. Am I missing some fundamental logic that is implemented in Flutter widget mechanics? There are no other runtime errors or debug messages showing up.

```
class ActualGame extends StatefulWidget {
  const ActualGame({super.key});

  @override
  State<ActualGame> createState() => _ActualGameState();
}

class _ActualGameState extends State<ActualGame> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    navigateToNextScreenAfterNSeconds(49);

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: appState.nextQuestion,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  side:
                      BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Text(
                  appState.currentQuestion,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigateToNextScreenAfterNSeconds(int seconds) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds), () {
      appState.updateSelectedIndex(2);
    });
  }
}
```

Code for PageController:

```
class PageController extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageController({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    Widget page;

    switch (appState.selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = Menu();
        break;
      case 1:
        page = ActualGame();
        break;
      case 2:
        page = AfterGame();
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError('Error! This page was not found');
    }

    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        // appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Appbar")),
        body: page,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

AppState Code:

```
class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  QuestionController q = QuestionController();
  String currentQuestion = '';

  MyAppState() {
    currentQuestion = q.nextQuestion();
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    currentQuestion = q.nextQuestion();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateSelectedIndex(int index) {
    selectedIndex = index;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: One immediate problem is that `navigateToNextScreenAfterNSeconds` is called *every time* your `build` method is called.  Furthermore, calling `navigateToNextScreenAfterNSeconds` multiple times will queue multiple updates.  Instead of using `Future.delayed`, you should use a `Timer` object, and then you can check if the `Timer` is already active before scheduling a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mbakabilal 's anwser was a step in the right direction, but since I am using `MyAppState`, I can't directly use it as a drop in replacement ([otherwise I get an error like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363665/dependoninheritedelement-was-called-before-initstate-in-flutter)). I needed to get `MyAppState` outside of the build function, and use null aware acces to be able to use it inside `initState`, this time using a timer as @jamesdlin suggested. This resulted in the following `_ActualGameState` class.

```
class _ActualGameState extends State<ActualGame> {
  Timer? timer;
  MyAppState? appState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(
        Duration(seconds: 49), (Timer t) => appState!.updateSelectedIndex(2));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: appState?.nextQuestion,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  side:
                      BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Text(
                  appState!.currentQuestion,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move the navigateToNextScreenAfterNSeconds(49); to initState, becuase it in in build it gets called each time the widgets rebuilds so it  would be called many times.