# Provider plus FutureBuilder in Stateless Widget Confusion

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

So, I've seen examples of using the `initState` function to load data (http) into a provider for a stateful widget. But if the widget is stateless, I'm not sure what the best approach is. What I've done is the following:

```
class GamesGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final gamesData = Provider.of<GamesProvider>(context);
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: gamesData.fetchGamesFromBgg(),
      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final games = gamesData.items;
          return GridView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              itemCount: games.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10),
              itemBuilder: (context, idx) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                  value: games[idx],
                  child: GameItem()
              )
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I'm just not sure that this is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling a future that needs to be displayed, you should be using a stateful widget and obtaining the future in `initState` or similar. Doing it during `build` is discouraged by the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and for good reason.

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or
> State.didChangeDependencies. **It must not be created during the
> State.build or StatelessWidget.build** method call when constructing the
> FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
> FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
> the asynchronous task will be restarted.

As the documentation states, if `GamesGrid` is rebuilt when obtaining the future in `build`, your future method will be called again, which should be undesirable behavior. *Every* time Flutter wants to build that widget, that function is going to be called again. If this is desirable behavior, you likely are using an antipattern somewhere else. Though if this widget is way at the top of your widget tree, it may not really make a difference. It's discouraged nonetheless.

---

Your code seems a bit odd to me and it can likely be refactored to be much more clear and better, but if you just want to quickly switch to the proper approach of obtaining the future in `initState` after converting to a `StatefulWidget`, you'll also need to access your provider `gamesData` value in `initState`, which can be accomplished with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61408104/13250142). You then store the `Future` in a variable and pass that variable to your `FutureBuilder`.

You should hopefully be able to figure it out from the examples using this pattern that you mentioned in your question. If not, I can whip up an example.

Comment: Thanks. It's odd to me that I need a Stateful Widget that doesn't really need to manage state, but that's for another discussion. :) Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use same way in statefulwidget also. Loading http data in initstate is not a good way.
One more thing, using statefulwidget or statelesswidget is totally depends up on  the output that you want to achieve. So, way you are using, is perfect.

Comment: This is incorrect. Using `initState` or similar is the undisputed proper method of handling futures. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68011588/13250142), specifically the linked and quoted documentation. As you'll see, `initState` is explicitly mentioned as a proper method of obtaining the future, while your suggestion of obtaining the future in `build` is explicitly discouraged.